# Column Formatting using JSON: Get value of the column “_ModerationStatus”

Tags: sharepoint-online, column, formatting, json-formatting

I'm trying to check the value of the column `_ModerationStatus` in a document library with that has content approval.

I have the following JSON:

```
 {
      "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
      "elmType": "div",
      "debugMode": true,
      "txtContent": "[$_ModerationStatus]"
}
```

I get the following message in the console:

> could not evaluate `_ModerationStatus`

The column is included in the view and the column displays **Approved** and so on. So the column seems to be working correctly.

What am I doing wrong? :)

Comment: Where is the column name `_ModerationStatus`?

Comment: Hi, what do you mean? :)

Comment: In the following JSON which you mention on your query, where is the column name `_ModerationStatus`?

Comment: Do you mean in the schema?

Comment: This question has already answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579077/how-can-i-programmatically-get-approval-status-in-sharepoint

Comment: Yes, but Im trying to do it with column formatting in a list where I can only write JSON. Sorry if I´m slow :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91606/discussion-between-utkarsh-dubey-and-perka).

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, we can create a text field "ApprovalStatus", then create a workflow to set the value from the "Approval Status" field to this new field.

Then using the JSON below:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "debugMode": true,
  "txtContent": "[$ApprovalStatus]"
}
```

Comment: Yes, that would work but I want the column to be updated instantly. Which cant be achieved with a flow, it would be some delay (15 minutes). :)

Comment: You can use a SharePoint designer workflow.